# Crosswalk for State Crime Statutes

Tags: data-request, metadata

I have arrest data from a number of cities across the United States and I'd like to make comparisons for the reasons of arrest. In this data, the reason for arrest is the state statute that the arrestee allegedly violated.

Are there resources that provide cross-walks between state crime statutes? I understand that statutes can be pretty different, but it would be very good to know, for example, the statutes that are related to the possession of drugs in different states.

Maybe one way of doing this would be to find a mapping of state statutes to Uniform Crime Reports.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but you maybe able to find something in [Hall of Criminal Justice](http://hallofjustice.sunlightfoundation.com/), a criminal justice metadata repository. disclosure, I work there and worked on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference librarians at a local law library were very helpful:

- [Alaska criminal statute cross-reference guide](https://www.ncjrs.gov/pdffiles1/Photocopy/142790NCJRS.pdf)
- [California Law Enforcement Code Tables: see Offense Codes by Code Section](https://oag.ca.gov/law/code-tables)
- [Illinois IUCR Offense Codes](https://www.isp.state.il.us/docs/6-260.pdf)
- [Pennsylvania Statute to UCR Cross-Reference](https://www.paucrs.pa.gov/UCR/Return_PDF/SectionUCRXREF.pdf)
- [New York UCR Cross-Reference Table](http://www.criminaljustice.ny.gov/crimnet/ojsa/crimereporting/ucr_refman/ucrxreftable.pdf)
- [North Dakota Offense Cross-Reference List](https://www.ag.nd.gov/bci/UCR/OffenseCrossreferencelist.pdf)